# Responsive Design resizing on desktop, not on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I'm using media queries to resize site elements based on width. I was developing and testing it on my desktop where it works perfectly, but as soon as I launched it and tested it on mobile (an iPhone 5) it does not resize at all - it displays at full width.

I have searched around for responses to this and the general consensus seems to be to set my viewport. But I have already done that — in my header I have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Is there something that I may have which may be overriding this?

My media queries look like this:

```
@media (min-width:320px) { /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ 
    #rlanguage {position: relative; right:0; border:red solid 0px;}
    #iX-nav {position: relative; right:0; border:red solid 01px;}
    #infoemail {display:none}
    #mainMenu {display:none}    
    #mobileMenu {display:inline}    
    #DeskTopOnly {display:none;}                            
    #MenuSpacing {width: 1px;}
    #iX-footer {width: 100%; height:auto}
    .GreenMenuLine {background:#000}                            
    .rootVoices TD.selected {padding: 0px;}
    .rootVoices TD.rootVoice {padding: 0px; width:10px}
}


@media (min-width:481px) { /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */ 
    #rlanguage {position: relative; float:right; border:orange solid 0px;}
    #iX-nav {position: relative; float:right; border:orange solid 0px;}
    #infoemail {display:none}
    #mainMenu {display:none}
    #mobileMenu {display:inline}
    #DeskTopOnly {display:none;}
    #MenuSpacing {width: 3px;}
    #iX-footer {width: 100%; height:auto}
    .GreenMenuLine {background:#000}                            
    .rootVoices TD.selected {padding: 0px;}
    .rootVoices TD.rootVoice {padding: 0px; width:0px}
}

@media (min-width:681px) { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */ 
    #rlanguage {position: relative; float:right; border:yellow solid 0px;}
    #iX-nav {position: relative; float:right; border:yellow solid 0px;}
    #infoemail {display:none}
    #mainMenu {display:inline}
    #mobileMenu {display:none}
    #DeskTopOnly {display:none;}
    #MenuSpacing {width: 2px;}
    #iX-footer {width: 100%; height:auto}
    .GreenMenuLine {background:#000}
    .rootVoices TD.selected {padding: 1px;}
    .rootVoices TD.rootVoice {padding: 1px; width:0px}
}


 @media (min-width:791px) { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops and desktops */ 
    #rlanguage {position: relative; float:left; border:green solid 0px;}
    #iX-nav {position: relative; float:left; border:green solid 0px;}
    #infoemail {display:inline}
    #mainMenu {display:inline}
    #mobileMenu {display:none}
    #DeskTopOnly {display:none;}
    #MenuSpacing {width: 12px;}
    #iX-footer {width: 100%;  height:auto}
    .GreenMenuLine {background:#000}
    .rootVoices TD.selected {padding-right: 10px; padding-left:10px;}
    .rootVoices TD.rootVoice {padding-right: 10px; padding-left:10px; width:12px}
}


@media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ 
    #rlanguage {position: relative; float:left; border:blue solid 0px;}
    #iX-nav {position: relative; float:left; border:blue solid 0px;}
    #infoemail {display:inline}
    #mainMenu {display:inline}
    #mobileMenu {display:none}
    #DeskTopOnly {display:inline;}
    #MenuSpacing {width: 15px;}
    #iX-footer {width: 100%;  height:auto}
    .GreenMenuLine {background:#000}
    .rootVoices TD.selected {padding-right: 20px; padding-left:20px;}
    .rootVoices TD.rootVoice {padding-right: 20px; padding-left:20px; width:12px}
}


@media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ 
    #rlanguage {position: relative; float:left; border:purple solid 0px;}
    #iX-nav {position: relative; float:left; border:purple solid 0px;}
    #infoemail {display:inline}
    #mainMenu {display:inline}
    #mobileMenu {display:none}
    #DeskTopOnly {display:inline;}
    #MenuSpacing {width: 18px;}
    #iX-footer {width: 100%; height:auto}
    .GreenMenuLine {background:#99cc33}
    .rootVoices TD.selected {padding-right: 24px; padding-left:24px;}
    .rootVoices TD.rootVoice {padding-right: 24px; padding-left:24px; width:12px
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use this viewport <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Explained here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Comment: yes, this is the first thing I did. I edited the question so that this string shows up. This answer does not seem to work for me.

Comment: In your head i see this: <meta name="viewport" content="width=1100">, you mean that something rewrite it?

Comment: @Patrick: could you clarify exactly what the problem is? I see three elements with a defined width: `#iX-footer`, which is set to 100% at all your breakpoints; `#MenuSpacing`, which is between 1 and 18 pixels wide; and `.rootVoices TD.rootVoice`, which is between 0 and 12. Which one of these isn’t behaving how you’d expect?

Comment: For example, on [this test page](http://cdn.pauldwaite.me.uk/test-pages/30648999/index.html), the box shows up as green on my iPhone 5C, using the same media query and meta viewport tag as you.

Comment: Germano, you found it! I had the viewport doubled across multiple locations, coupled with changing the @media min width mentioned below made the change. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Patrick: are you sure you need to change the `@media` min-width? Because that really doesn’t look necessary.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, it wasn't working before that change and it now is. Both changes seem necessary to get what I was trying to do.

Comment: @Patrick: cool cool. As I’ve said, it really seems unlikely to me that a `min-width` of 314 pixels is required, but I’m sure I must be missing something. (I know it doesn’t really matter now you’ve got it working, but I’m still not clear on what you were trying to do, and what wasn’t working.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite told ya so...

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: you sure did. (Although I’m still waiting to see a working code example where styles apply to an iPhone 5 with a media query of `min-width: 314px`, but don’t with `min-width: 320px`.)

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: obviously I’ve got a personal interest in that, because I think I’m right, but this would be a better question and answer with a code example. At the moment it doesn’t explain anything to anyone other than the original poster.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I will build a test page for you when I get home tonight, This issue happens only with sizes, never with fonts, colors ect. And I have never found a good reason why its the case.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: cool, I look forward to seeing it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set your first @media min width to 300px. The Iphone 5 is around 314px and is why your media query is not working.

Comment: The iPhone 5’s screen width is 320 pixels, just like every iPhone that came before it.

Comment: @Paul, you are wrong. Iphone 5 has a high pixel density for such a small screen. If setting the min-view width less than 314px will solve his problem.

Comment: Looks like [Wikipedia’s wrong too then](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_5). As it says under the display section in the info box, the screen is 1,136 x 640 physical pixels, and at 2x resolution that’s [320 CSS pixels](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html) (640/2 = 320).

Comment: Wow dude, for being as smart as you think you are. you don't get it. pixels vs pixel density is what you should be looking at. I stand by what I said before aprox. 314px for iphone5 you need to be schooled start reading http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Comment: Besides, it will fix his problem. So what is the issue?

Comment: If you’d like to provide a code sample showing it fixing the problem (for example, using [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), although I think code examples can be run directly in Stack Overflow answers now), that’d be great.

Comment: For example, [on this test page](http://cdn.pauldwaite.me.uk/test-pages/30648999/index.html), the box shows up as green on my iPhone 5C, with not a single 314-pixel media query in sight. But please, dude, school me.

Comment: Wrong test, next time set sizes.

Comment: You’ve lost me. What has that got to do with the question? Could you provide an example of the right test?

Comment: Adam, Thank you, this did solve my issue! I grabbed the numbers elsewhere and trusted them. I needed the change in size to get this to implement.